# Custom date format in Excel for zero

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am new to excel and C#. I am fetching data from database and showing in excel. In a array when ever there is a null record I am replacing it with '0'. My issue is after I format the column to a date format '0' is replaced by default value '1/0/1900'.  I need a custom format which will format only date records and but not zeros.

Note:In below Code Data= contains array of records. CreateDataArray will check for null records and will replace by `0`.

```
object[,] updateValues = CreateDataArray(data, 1, direction);
        IRange dataRange = _rangeHelper.GetRangeBeside(startCell, data.Length - 1, direction);
        dataRange.Value2 = updateValues;

        // Apply format
        dataRange.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy";
        dataRange.NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy";
```

[image: as shown in below image my output should be like expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataRange.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy;;#0";
```